# Add a new API endpoint with Flask AppBuilder in Superset (through Flask Blueprints)

Tags: python, flask, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I am using Superset 2.0.0 and I saw that it was possible to extend the API (i.e. add new endpoints using Flask Blueprints).

I can add a simple endpoint with the code:

```py
# superset_config.py
from greeting import greeting

BLUEPRINTS = [greeting]
```

```py
# greeting.py
from flask import Blueprint

greeting = Blueprint("greeting", __name__)

@greeting.route("/hello")
def health_status():
    return "Hello"
```

But I would like to use endpoint protections that Superset uses so that my endpoint is only accessible after being authenticated (which means providing the JWT token generated using the `/api/v1/security/login` endpoint).

The [Superset API](https://superset.apache.org/docs/api/) is based on Flask Appbuilder so I tried this:

```py
# superset_config.py
from greeting import GreetingApi

BLUEPRINTS = [GreetingApi]
```

```py
# greeting.py
from flask_appbuilder.api import BaseApi, expose, protect


class GreetingApi(BaseApi):
    csrf_exempt = False

    @protect
    @expose("/hello")
    def greeting(self):
        return self.response(200, message="Hello")
```

But it does not register the blueprint and I don't know if this piece of code would be enough to ensure that this endpoint is not accessible to everyone.

Do you have any idea how to do this? I am a beginner on Flask...

Thanks a lot!

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just missed to add :

`appbuilder.add_api(GreetingApi)`